# JSON to SQL Table with nested properties

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I am trying to develop database table structure from following JSON Structure. "requiredfields" are straight forward and I table setup for those. However, I am stuck on how to created schema to store "Configuration" and its nested properties in SQL Database. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
{
    "requiredFields": [
        "hello",
        "world"
    ],
    "configuration": {
        "hello": {
            "fallbacks": [
                {
                    "type": "constant",
                    "value": "30"
                }
            ]
        },
        "world": {
            "fallbacks": [
                {
                    "type": "fromInputFile",
                    "value": "patientFirstName"
                },
                {
                    "type": "fromInputFile",
                    "value": "subscriberFirstName"
                },
                {
                    "type": "constant",
                    "value": "alpha"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you could store that in a single table

```sql
CREATE TABLE ConfigurationFallbacks (
    field nvarchar(100),
    type nvarchar(100),
    value nvarchar(100)
);
```

You may also want to add another table to store just the `field` values, and the table above would be foreign-keyed to that.

You can insert like this:

```
INSERT ConfigurationFallbacks (field, type, value)
SELECT
  keys.[key],
  j.type,
  j.value
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.configuration') keys
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(keys.value, '$.fallbacks')
  WITH (
    type nvarchar(100),
    value nvarchar(100)    
  ) j;
```

The first `OPENJSON` call does not have a schema, so it returns a set of `key` `value` pairs.